# How to interpret text from other file as lua code

Tags: lua

Suppose I have a simple text file named `random.txt`. It has the following lines.

```
a = "apple"
b = "ball"
```

As this is the syntax followed in Lua for declaring variables, I want it to be read and interpreted as a Lua code.

```lua
file = io.open("random.txt", "a+")
content = file:read "*a"
print(a)
```

Now technically the `content` variable has the meaning of `a` and `b` stored in it, but I don't know how to read the Lua part ***from*** `content`.

Is it possible?

Comment: rename `random.txt` to `random.lua` and use `require("random")` or use `loadfile()`

Comment: Try `dofile"random.txt"`.

Comment: @lhf thanks a lot. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `dofile` function like this:

```lua
dofile "random.txt"
```

and then you can access the declarations inside your foreign file

thanks to [How to interpret text from other file as lua code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69666123/how-to-interpret-text-from-other-file-as-lua-code/69686728?noredirect=1#comment123141072_69666123)

Comment: Thanks, but this was already clarified in a comment, you might want to mention them in your answer.